# workaround to make exporting environment variable from makefile possible

Tags: makefile, environment-variables, gnu-make

i have a tricky conundrum for you all!

i would like to set environment variables with a makefile. i know, that the called process cannot change the calling environment's variables, but there has to be some workaround.

**in the makefile:**

```
target:
    export VAR=test
```

**later, in the terminal:**

```
echo $VAR
```

should print "test".

how can this be achieved with some kind of workaround?

thank you very much for any help!

Comment: "There has to be some workaround" - what makes you say that? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Andreas says, there is no "workaround" for this.  It's a fundamental feature of a POSIX operating system.  The *only* way for the parent process (e.g. a shell) to have its environment modified is by doing something different than simply run `make`.  If you're willing to do that, then you have options.

For example, if your makefile does this:

```
target:
        @echo 'export VAR=test'
```

then in your shell you can do this:

```
$ eval $(make target)
```

and now that variable will be set.  Of course, this will fail miserably if your makefile prints **ANYTHING** except valid shell syntax so you can only do a very limited set of things.

Alternatively you can have the makefile write stuff to a file then source the file, like this:

```
target:
        echo 'export VAR=test' > target
```

then:

```
$ make target
$ . target
```

Comment: Printing an export command is nice. User can then copy-paste into terminal. Safe and sound.

Answer (score 1):

Make does updates to files, so what you need to do is "export" the variable to a file, and then later in terminal call something using the content of the file. Possible convoluted solution:

```
-- Makefile --
target:
    echo "test" > VAR

-- Terminal --
cat VAR;              # Prints var content, like echo does
cat VAR | xargs echo; # Sends each token (?) as argument to echo, printing it.
                      # Here be dragons.
```